# Android Context Deprecated

Tags: android, android-context

`Context` for android has been deprecated.
What is the alternative for that?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: No way that `Context` is deprecated , show your imports

Comment: Seems a big joke by editor. :D

Comment: import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.widget.TextView;

these are my imports @Redman

Comment: Pretty sure it's just IDE messing around. Try "Invalidate cache and restart" from `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Answer (score 1):

It seems life of component is deprecated. I shocked while reading your question. Context is not deprecated. You can see more at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.

Check your import. Correct import is `android.content.Context`

Comment: And I also checked the doc you suggested and searched everywhere . Nowhere is the thing mentioned, But still its in my studio....

Comment: @swatikapoor Try cleaning your project. No known reason for that. What is target version by the way ? And what is say when you click on more?

Comment: please check the edited post .. adding image here is not allowed

Comment: it doesn't goes after cleaning my project too.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to figure this out myself. It seems if I just ignore it, even though it shows as <strike>Context</strike> the project will still run as intended.

However if you really want to rid yourself of it, just hide it...

> 1. Click on <strike>Context</strike>
> 2. Click on "Inspection" Lightbulb that appears on the left side of your code
> 3. Choose "Inspection 'Deprecated API usage' options
> 4. Click "Disable Inspection"

That should clear your Deprecated warning.